# SSRS Bubble Chart Lines

Tags: reporting-services, bubble-chart

Is it possible to hide data label lines in a bubble chart. I cannot seem to find a way to hide the lines. I have tried using 'No Colour' in the ÇalloutLineColor section of the chart but it wont allow you to use a transparent colour. 
What i want is to have all the names next to the bubble chart as is showing in the image below, but i want to remove the lines that point to the bubble from the name.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
After disabling the smart label options, i am know getting the names overlapping. I changed the Rotation and Inclination to 0 but the names are still overlapping. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the Chart Series Under `SmartLabels` set `Disabled` to `True`

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! this worked! However, now i have the names overlapping. I have posted a photo in the Edit. Is it possible to stop the names from overlapping?